# Unexplained 503 errors when uploading huge file to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I'm trying to upload a rather huge file (~1TB) to Google Drive using their [resumable uploads](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#resumable) feature. I upload the file in 16MB chunks. This job has been running for a couple of days successfully already; I'm uploading over a very slow link and I want it to run robustly for even weeks.

For this particular upload, after around 60GB are uploaded fine, I repeatedly see the following error; I do an exponential backoff to retry; it's capped to retry every two minutes after each failure.

The request and response look like this (the request is passed to an [OAuth'd `http.Client`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2/google), so the `Authorization` header isn't included):

```
2015/04/18 09:26:28 Attempt 663 failed for this chunk: expected status 308, but got 503

tried this request:
2015/04/18 09:26:28 &{PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2UqOogB7qWwFhp7afkT-uYYGWodnUo5GNXpNbhvxceY2C01JZgz0m79zQi_LzAY1zGwkrv4fcE6Jh9NWNhpvwQqvePW0-A 
    HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Range:[bytes 62730010624-62746787839/*]] 
    {0xc2104256c0} 16777216 [] false www.googleapis.com map[] map[] <nil> map[]   <nil>}

got this response:
2015/04/18 09:26:28 &{503 Service Unavailable 503 HTTP/1.1 1 1
    map[Content-Length:[0] Date:[Sat, 18 Apr 2015 07:28:47 GMT]
    Server:[UploadServer ("Built on Apr 9 2015 13:51:25 (1428612685)")] 
    Content-Type:[text/html; charset=UTF-8]
    Alternate-Protocol:[443:quic,p=1]] 0xc2100e8ba0 0 [] true map[] 0xc2104228f0}
```

The response body is empty.
Interestingly, I see these errors in the Google Developers Console's dashboard (the error count is increasing). However, I can't find detailed reports on what went wrong anywhere -- neither in the "Monitoring" tabs or in the detailed API usage report for the Drive API.

That means the errors are correctly assigned to my account (which rules out auth problems), and the error is with this specific upload (another upload of a different file works) and not the uploader code in general.

Therefore, I suspect this is Google's bug and not mine.

What is going on here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs to be addressed to Google. They are the only ones who have the access necessary to diagnose this.

Comment: Their support is surprisingly responsive and competent if you're paying them for a service.